# limiting the number (or size) or outstanding intermediate outputs to be processed

Tags: snakemake

I have a workflow where an earlier, faster, step produces a large intermediate output that is then consumed by a slower subsequent step.  As an example, imagine a workflow that decompresses gzip files and recompresses them with bzip2.

Here's an untested example to illustrate my problem:

```
rule decompress:
  input:
    "gz/{dataset}.dat.gz"
  output:
    temp("decompress/{dataset}.dat")
  shell:
    "gunzip -c ${input} > ${output}"

rule compress:
  input:
    "decompress/{dataset}.dat"
  output:
    "bzip/{dataset}.dat.bz2"
  shell:
    "bzip2 -c ${input} > ${output}"
```

My problem is that the since the `decompress` step runs faster than the second `compress`, it tends to fill up my disk space with uncompressed files.  I'm wondering, is there a way for me to limit the number (or size) or intermediate datasets in this scenario that are waiting to be processed by the latter, slower rule?

Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible to combine these two rules into one? Then use `--jobs` to limit the number of jobs in parallel, at least it can guarantee that new job won't be started until one of the previous has finished

Comment: You could also try [job grouping](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#defining-groups-for-execution) and lower down the number of jobs in parallel.

Comment: Regarding combining these two rules into one, I prefer not to.  The two steps have different resource requirements and I get better resource utilization by splitting them.

Comment: One option that you could try is specifying a higher priority to the `compress` rule. That way if a decompressed file is available the `compress` rule will be preffered over `decompress` for a new file. [Details](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#priorities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to specify arbitrary resources, for example:

```py
rule decompress:
  input:
    "gz/{dataset}.dat.gz"
  output:
    temp("decompress/{dataset}.dat")
  resources:
    # this is arbitrary name to control how many
    # jobs can run at the same time (will control
    # by specifying resource availability/constraint)
    limit_space=1,
  shell:
    "gunzip -c ${input} > ${output}"

rule compress:
  input:
    "decompress/{dataset}.dat"
  output:
    "bzip/{dataset}.dat.bz2"
  resources:
    # note that compress/decompress are now
    # competing for the limited resource
    limit_space=1,
  priority:
    # so specifying a higher priority for this
    # rule will make sure that it runs before
    # decompress rule
    100,
  shell:
    "bzip2 -c ${input} > ${output}"
```

To specify the `resource` constraint, you can use `cli`:

```sh
snakemake --resources limit_space=6
```

There is more details in the [docs on resources](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources).

Update: as pointed out in the comments, the command above will initially launch 6 instances of `decompress` rule and then as they are completed, launch new `compress` instances one by one. The maximum number of executed `decompress` instances is 6 (if there's more than one completed decompress instance, then the next freed up resource slot will be taken by `compress` rule).

Also, using a dedicated resource could be useful when there are other rules competing for cores, so by having a dedicated resource, the constraint specific to decompress/compress is isolated.

Comment: Wouldn't you have at most 6 instances of the decompress rule running? (e.g., at workflow start, when no compress rules can be run)

This seems like a complete solution, though in practice specifying a higher priority for the compression rule (as first suggested by @pd321) may be sufficient.  Using only priority would break if the first "wave" of decompression jobs (the ones scheduled right at the start of the workflow) fills the space. However, other limited resources (e.g., cores) also serve to limit the size of that wave.

Comment: Hmm, you're right! At the start of the process, there can be 6 decompress rules running, however as soon as 3 of them complete, 3 compress instances will run, which will use up all the `limit_space` resource, so new decompress rules will start only when the compress rules free up resource slots... but at peak, it's possible to have 6 decompress or 6 compress rules running (or some combinations of them).

Comment: As for using `cores` to control size of waves, that's plausible, but having dedicated resource might be better if you have other rules that are also competing for cores but could execute in parallel.